# Call to undefined method [loadRoutesFrom] error in laravel 5.2 after installing jeremykenedy-laravel-logger package

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed jeremykenedy-laravel-logger package to record the activity but after installing when I tried to migrate the table its showing Call to undefined method [loadRoutesFrom] error how to fix it?

package link:-https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run below command in your term :

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: hi saurabh whenever i run the command i am getting the same error

Comment: @NithishPK: Please check this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-loadroutesfrom-in-service-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php artisan config:cache`

then

run also `php artisan dump-autoload`

after your installation.

Comment: its giving me the same error for all artisan commands how to fix these

Comment: i am using laravel 5.2

Comment: did you register the package in your config/app.php under providers?

Comment: yes i did that after  when i tried to migrate the table I am getting the error

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-loadroutesfrom-in-service-provider I think the error is not in the package, See this it might help you.

Comment: It seems @MONSTEEEER found the issue. It's in the package. For older versions, `loadRoutesFrom()` is not available in the ServiceProvider.

Comment: If upgrading to 5.3 is not an option, you need to replace the `ServiceProvider` with the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: @Mozammil can you give some more detail? I'm currently going through this and would appreciate the help :)